# How do I make sure a regex matches one occurrence of a pattern

Tags: regex, xpages

This is my regex:

```
var re = /[a-zA-Z]{6}[0-9]{4}$/;
if (storageTrayId == "") {
return false;
} else if(!re.test(storageTrayId)) {
alert('Storage Tray ID must be in the format \n ssstttnnnn (where sss is an alphabetic identifier for the Bulk File Center, ttt is an alphabetic identifer for the bundle type stored, and nnnn is the sequence number)');
 return false;
};
```

It matches correctly if I enter a properly formatted value (eg. BALTEL0001) and an improper value (eg. BT001 or BALTEL0001BT0001).  However, it also matches if I enter BALTEL0001BALTEL0002.  I need it to match only if the value is one occurrence of the pattern.  I'm sure it's something simple but I haven't hit on it.

Comment: Try this expression : `/^([a-zA-Z]{6}[0-9]{4})$/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add the start anchor.
Your updated regex would look like this.

```
/^[a-zA-Z]{6}[0-9]{4}$/
```

Answer (score 4):

here have a test : `var re = /^[a-zA-Z]{6}[0-9]{4}$/;`